# Missing data in web service and mysql during database downtime?

Tags: mysql, web-services

We have simple php web service that receives json post from an automated application. This automated application will only post once to our web service. The problem is that, when the database connection is lost, we lost also the json.

What is the best approach to prevent such issue?

Comment: You can out the post request data into maybe a flat file and then attempt the insert/update from there and remove the flat file data based on the insert success/failure status?

Comment: First option I have in mind is to log the failed posted json and create a script that process the log as cron job